# Text in editor is grayed out

Tags: texmaker, editors

Everything is working well, but for some reason the text in the editor part is very light. On my other laptop it works fine... See pic[image]

Comment: Looks like its color management or associated settings are distorted. Do you observe similar differences, e.g for pictures, webpages etc.? Do you have a program active against eye strains (blue parts of the spectrum)?

Comment: No, it's really just happening on Texmaker... I dont have any program against eye strains

Answer (score 0):

`Representing color on a computer` is a complex subject. It involves at least:

- graphics card
- its drivers
- monitor (settings + technology)
- operating systems interventions
- ambient light
- personals eyes conditions (including diseases)

where the first 4 can be varied via parameter settings.

---

**Solution**: Check and adjust the following on your bad computer.

---

**Texmaker**: If you go for `Options/Configure Texmaker/Editor` you'll see the following settings for the `Default Theme`, where I translated the hex-values into the interior colors for some:

[image: TMs color settings]

Assuming your values do match, I suspect you even can't see the white in this image, comparing with your screen-foto, even in the pdf-preview. Besides the settings you can access easily (*contrast, saturation,temperature etc.*) most likely your computer has an inappropriate Gamma value set, which is one out of several parameters which could gray-out a colored image.

---

**Monitorcalibration ...** might be a good search term for you, which yields for me at least:

- [Understanding how to calibrat your monitor (Adobe)](https://www.adobe.com/creativecloud/video/discover/how-to-calibrate-monitor.html)
- [How to calibrate your monitor ...](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-calibrate-your-monitor/)

The latter one both:

- guides you through OS settings relevant here
- links to [test images](https://tft.vanity.dk/MonitorTest_pureHTML.html)

If you go for the `Color gradient` I suspect that the left region may appear quite unresolved, grayish, "flat" on your bad computer.

[image: colors]