# Drawing multiple arrows to the same complex with chemfig

Tags: macros, chemfig

I'm currently trying to draw a chemical reaction network in latex using chemfig, however I have got stuck when drawing multiple arrows to the same complex within a linkage class. Here is my script so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\newcommand{\aaa}{A_1}
\newcommand{\bb}{B_1}
\newcommand{\cc}{C_1}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \schemestart
    \subscheme{$\aaa + \bb$}
    \arrow{<=>[$k_1$][$k_{-1}$]}
    \chemfig{\cc}
    \arrow{->[$k_{\cc}$]}
    \chemfig{\varnothing}
    \arrow{<-[$k_{\aaa}$]}[90]
    \chemfig{\aaa}
    \schemestop
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

where `\aaa,\bb` and `\cc` are macros that I've defined. I want to create another complex, `\chemfig{\bb}` with another arrow pointing towards `\chemfig{\varnothing}` from the opposite side of `\chemfig{\cc}` but I'm not sure how to do this. From what I've read from the documentation it is possible to do this if you label your chemicals as `A,B,` etc but I don't know how to do this when using custom macros. To give another example:
[image]

This example I found contains multiple complexes decaying to 0 from multiple directions. I want to do the same in my diagram.

Comment: If you look at both the answers and their comments there seems to be some opportunity left in your question to clarify the speculations and assumptions made ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think the function you are looking for is `branching`, see *IV 7 Branching* in the manual.

Below I sketch the key structure, as I read it from your question, neglecting directions and labels to better show what's important. A few remarks:

- while you develop a drawing, it's better to use class `standalone`
- you can compile them separately and later include the pdf via `\includegraphics` from package `graphicx`
- `chemfig` is built on `Tikz`, but abstracts many things to simplify most chemical drawings; so you basically kind of *"draw from left to right"*
- so one thing you'd need is not too obvious at first glance: node positions of nodes you already placed
- `chemfig`s alternative is using `@` inside the arguments of `\arrow`
- so here I associate `@a` as the position of whatever is drawn in the place of `A`

So instead of going from A to B to .. E the "plotter" returns to @a all the time and restarts from there. The names (a, bb etc.) are not important and you seem to be free in naming them.

`subscheme`s may or may not be useful for your task, and you certainly can combine them with branching.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}


\begin{document}

 \schemestart
    A\arrow(a--bb)      B
    \arrow(@a--cc)[ 90] C
    \arrow(@a--dd)[180] D
    \arrow(@a--ee)[-90] E
 \schemestop

\end{document}
```

---

**P.S.** For faster results I suggest this process:

- create the structure of your overall scheme first, like I showed, using placeholders like A, B, C etc., compile
- next, adjust arrow direction and type
- next start replacing some of the placeholders with chemical formulas or compounds
- next add labels to the arrows where needed
- next replace them or parts of them with one or more macros: clarity and convenience should be your guides
- continue this iterative process until you both created your final scheme AND clean code (it‘s easy to write sth. ugly which is hard to read a day or week later)
- use comments right from the start in your code: it‘s a simple life saver

---

**Example** following said process:

Step-by-step development:

[image: dev]

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

 % ~~~ following the process for the 3rd example given ~~~
 % ~~~ 1. overall structure
 \schemestart
    A\arrow(s1--zero) B 
     \arrow C
     \arrow(@zero--p)[-90] P
 \schemestop

 % ~~~ 2. arrow directions and types ~~~
 \schemestart
    A\arrow(s1--zero){<=>}      B 
     \arrow          {<=>}      C
     \arrow(@zero--p){<-}[-90]  P
 \schemestop

 % ~~~ 3. replacing placeholders ~~~
 \schemestart
    S1\arrow(s1--zero){<=>}     0 
     \arrow          {<=>}      S2
     \arrow(@zero--p){<-}[-90]  P
 \schemestop

 % ~~~ 4. adding labels ~~~
 \schemestart
    S1\arrow(s1--zero){<=>[$\zeta_{S1}$][$F_{S1}$]}     0 
      \arrow          {<=>[$\zeta_{S1}$][$F_{S2}$]}     S2
      \arrow(@zero--p){<-[(above)][*{0}$\zeta_P$]}[-90] P
 \schemestop

\end{document}
```

At this point I'd stop the process, as further steps are neither needed nor useful, unless the overall context (dozens of similar reactions) demands further refactoring, e.g. as preparation steps; this code seems to be clean and clear enough (to me) :

```
% ~~~ delete everything else ~~~
 \schemestart
    S1\arrow(s1--zero){<=>[$\zeta_{S1}$][$F_{S1}$]}     0 
      \arrow          {<=>[$\zeta_{S1}$][$F_{S2}$]}     S2
      \arrow(@zero--p){<-[][*{0}$\zeta_P$]}[-90]    P
 \schemestop
```

**BTW**, if the direction AND label towards S2 are important, you need some way to interchange things. The obvious one would be to exchange labels, like `[above][below]` against `[below][above]`.

Comment: As I understand the question, the OP is asking specifically about branching when macros are used to name the nodes rather than naming them directly. But maybe I misunderstood?

Comment: That‘s a good question to the OP. To me it looks like macros shall replace more complex structures, which is fine. However, my overall impression is trying to cope with many new things at once, where creating arbitrary reaction schemes seem to be the major road block. // In terms of macros, i.e. refactoring, the macros should be a bit different. In the example posted they don’t create more evident code, but rather increase code noise, at least to me.

Comment: I don't disagree, but I suspect they are simplified for the example. Or maybe because they may need to be altered later. But oversimplified macro names are rarely a good idea in the long term. On the other hand, does anybody *not* think they're a fantastic idea when they first start using LaTeX?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use macros for names, you can override the default naming scheme using the optional `(<name1>--<name2>)` directly after `\arrow`. Where `<name1>` or both names refer to existing nodes, use the `@` syntax to reference them.

For example,

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\newcommand{\aaa}{A_1}
\newcommand{\bb}{B_1}
\newcommand{\cc}{C_1}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
  \subscheme{$\aaa + \bb$}
  \arrow(sssb--cc){<=>[$k_1$][$k_{-1}$]}
  \chemfig{\cc}
  \arrow(@cc--vn){->[$k_{\cc}$]}
  \chemfig{\varnothing}
  \arrow(@vn--aaa){<-[$k_{\aaa}$]}[90]
  \chemfig{\aaa}
  \arrow(@vn--bb){<-[$k_{\bb}$]}
  \chemfig{\bb}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

produces the output I think you want. My usual method of producing images to paste into posts currently produces screw-ups, so this is an experiment to see if I can get something better from Overleaf. Unfortunately, I ended up having to use a screenshot as they no longer seem to support creating images.

[image: screenshot of output rendered on Overleaf]

This is better than Okular currently gives me, but why is it so dark?

Comment: A dark screenshot can have many reasons. One are monitor settings, see e.g. here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709635/245790 . Sometimes images, perhaps even screenshots taken from programs, twiddle with the alpha channel of the bitmap, resulting in black, usually. // From the non-uniform background in your screenshot I suspect your monitor settings being more relevant for this artifact.

Comment: So this was exactly what I was looking for. This has solved the problem for me. Thank you for your help. However, I don't quite understand how you know what the right name was when drawing arrows. For example, I understand why `aaa` corresponds to `\chemfig{\aaa}`, but I don't understand why `@vn` corresponds to `\chemfig{\varnothing}` or `sssb` corresponds to `\subscheme{$\aaa + \bb$}`. From my understanding, it is not possible to provide a name for each `\chemfig{}` or `\subscheme{}`?

Comment: That‘s coincidence with different things that look „the same“. I.e. there‘s a difference between a macro call in its complete version \bb{}, which expands into B_1, and (simplified) a coordinate name bb, which can be recalled by @bb … There‘s no automagic, as cfr introduced those coordinate names one by one inside the \arrow statements. // To safeguard myself I wouldn’t have used such similarities.

Comment: @George As MS-SPO says, the relationship between `aaa` and `\aaa` was just because that seemed a convenient name. I could have called it `bob` and perhaps the second point is right, too: it would have been better if I'd chosen unrelated names. I chose `vn` just because it is convenient shorthand for `variable nothing` and `sssb` was supposed to be `ssab`, I think, for 'sub-scheme involving A and B`.

Answer (score 0):

Let me take this opportunity to illustrate how useful it is to follow a [process](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/714205/245790), like I lined out in [my other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/714205/245790), best combined with refactoring, best in its `Test-Driven-Design (TDD)` approach (we do it automatically by the compile step AND looking at the result (=test)).

#### (A) The final result (after having followed said process)

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand\cA[0]{A_1}
\newcommand\cB[0]{B_1}
\newcommand\cC[0]{C_1}
\newcommand\kr[1]{$k_{#1}$}% k-r eplacement

\begin{document}
 \schemestart
    \chemfig{\cA{} + \cB}
     \arrow         {<=>[$k_1$][$k_{-1}$]}  \chemfig{\cC}
     \arrow(t--u)   {->[\kr{\cC}][]}        \chemfig{\varnothing} 
     \arrow         {<-[\kr{\cB}]}          \chemfig{\cB}
     \arrow(@u--w)  {<-[\kr{\cA}]}[90]      \chemfig{\cA}
 \schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image: final]

#### (B) Following said process

See, how the code evolved almost by itself in almost no time, step-by-step. Less thinking, more results.

Is step #5 really necessary? That depends. It can be a matter of taste or preferences, or it may prepare something more complex which you know is about to follow.

Does it have to stop here? Yes and No. You may like, what was achieved. You may dislike the clumsy looking `\kr{\cC}` calls: why not having a few macros with 0 argument, i.e. providing constant text? All are valid considerations. It depends only on where you want to go or arrive at.

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

% ~~~ introduced in step #3 ~~~
\usepackage{amssymb}

% ~~~ introduced in step #5a ~~~
\newcommand\cA[0]{A_1}
\newcommand\cB[0]{B_1}
\newcommand\cC[0]{C_1}

% ~~~ introduced in step #5b ~~~~~~~
\newcommand\kr[1]{$k_{#1}$}% k-r eplacement

\begin{document}

 % ~~~ following the process for the 3rd example given ~~~
 % ~~~ 1. overall structure using silly names
 \schemestart
    S\arrow T \arrow(t--u) U \arrow V
    \arrow(@u--w)[90]W
 \schemestop

 % ~~~ 2. arrow directions and types ~~~
 %        kindly watch the minimalistic use of coordinates
 %        (t--u) is only needed to recall @u
 \schemestart
    S
     \arrow         {<=>}       T 
     \arrow(t--u)               U 
     \arrow         {<-}        V
     \arrow(@u--w)  {<-}[90]    W
 \schemestop


 % ~~~ 3. replacing placeholders ~~~
 \schemestart
    \chemfig{A_1 + B_1}
     \arrow         {<=>}       \chemfig{C_1}
     \arrow(t--u)               \chemfig{\varnothing} 
     \arrow         {<-}        \chemfig{B_1}
     \arrow(@u--w)  {<-}[90]    \chemfig{A_1}
 \schemestop


 % ~~~ 4. adding labels ~~~
 \schemestart
    \chemfig{A_1 + B_1}
     \arrow         {<=>[$k_1$][$k_{-1}$]}  \chemfig{C_1}
     \arrow(t--u)   {->[$k_{C_1}$][]}       \chemfig{\varnothing} 
     \arrow         {<-[$k_{B_1}$]}         \chemfig{B_1}
     \arrow(@u--w)  {<-[$k_{A_1}$]}[90]     \chemfig{A_1}
 \schemestop


 % ~~~ 5. introducing useful (?) macro shortcuts ~~~
 %     5a.   intermediate result: let's remove most k's !
 \schemestart
    \chemfig{\cA{} + \cB}
     \arrow         {<=>[$k_1$][$k_{-1}$]}  \chemfig{\cC}
     \arrow(t--u)   {->[$k_{\cC}$][]}       \chemfig{\varnothing} 
     \arrow         {<-[$k_{\cB}$]}         \chemfig{\cB}
     \arrow(@u--w)  {<-[$k_{\cA}$]}[90]     \chemfig{\cA}
 \schemestop

 %      5b.  the outcome
 \schemestart
    \chemfig{\cA{} + \cB}
     \arrow         {<=>[$k_1$][$k_{-1}$]}  \chemfig{\cC}
     \arrow(t--u)   {->[\kr{\cC}][]}        \chemfig{\varnothing} 
     \arrow         {<-[\kr{\cB}]}          \chemfig{\cB}
     \arrow(@u--w)  {<-[\kr{\cA}]}[90]      \chemfig{\cA}
 \schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image: evolution]